# How to use FormData in node.js without Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, multipartform-data, form-data

I want to make a post request in nodejs without browser since it is backend code.

```
const formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('chartfile', file);
```

But above code gives me error as `FormData not defined`.
I am working with ES6.

Anybody, who can let me know how to use the FormData in nodejs?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) - npm module.

Use it this way,

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
 
var form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am working with ES6 so
I imported like this:`import FormData from 'form-data'`

But I get error `form_data_1.default is not a contructor`

Comment: If its node js, you only can do `var FormData = require('form-data');`  Node JS  doesn't support ES6 syntaxt for importing.

Comment: I am using esm module to use ES6 syntax.

Comment: try `import * as FormData from form-data`

Comment: Thanks. I get another error `source.on is not a function`. Sorry for my poor question

Comment: dont know, refer document or ask in github repo ?

Comment: @AdelinIonut did you found any solution to the `source.on is not a function` error?

Comment: How to pass additional headers which should not be send via post parameters as if i don't use bodyParams.getHeaders() it does not pass post parameters and if i append secret token in headers then it even sends it as post or headers.

Comment: no need, `new URLSearchParams()` does the same exact thing

Comment: @AdelinIonut, did you try `import * as FormData from 'form-data'`?

Comment: @RadicalEdward I am sending the file from a frontend app and using multer middleware. When I append the `my_file` field for example, do I still need to use `fs.createReadStream` or is there another way that I can pass the file directly?

Comment: `source.on is not a function` usually means that you have to stringify the content (`JSON.stringify`)

Comment: `FormData` is a Node API [starting with Node 18](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 64):

**If you only need to submit `string` values and not `Buffer` or `ReadStream`, then `URLSearchParams` can work for you!**

Original Example

```js
var fs = require('fs');
 
var form = new URLSearchParams();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_second_field', 'my value 2');
form.append('my_third_field', 'my value 3');
```

Axios Example

```js
const formData = new URLSearchParams();
formData.append('field1', 'value1');
formData.append('field2', 'value2');
const response = await axios.request({
  url: 'https://example.com',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: formData
});
```

Comment: @OMKARAGRAWAL you should have just edited this one or contributed it here, forking when its not needed just adds to noise. like what was the point

Comment: This does not work as described. URLSearchParams only accepts a string as a value, so a ReadStream or Buffer are not valid. Therefore, this is not equivalent to FormData.

Comment: This is not going to work if the request is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: That's totally wrong! URLSearchParams and FormData are two different things and it will not work.

Comment: The question is for node.js not for web api

Comment: Is there possible to send array as field ?

Answer (score 30):

`FormData` is now a part of Node 18. They removed the experimental warning they introduced in Node 17: https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/d33cbabd79

Now you can use it with `fetch` without any dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

`FormData` is a part of JS web API (not included in native NodeJS). You can install the [`form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package instead.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know how to use that module in ES6 syntax?

Comment: `import * as FormData from "form-data";`

Comment: For me this is what worked: 
`import { default as FormData } from "form-data";`

Comment: @AdelinIonut @DenesTarjan for me it works even simpler `import FormData from "form-data";`

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion the cleanest solution that requires no additional dependencies is:

```
const formData = new URLSearchParams({
  param1: 'this',
  param2: 'is',
  param3: 'neat',
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the npm module [formdata-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node) because it's a complete (spec-compliant) [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) implementation for Node.js. It supports both ESM/CJS targets, so EM6 is supported. You can find a few examples at the [npm module page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node).

Answer (score -2):

```
 let _data = new FormData();
_data.append(`FaceDataRecord', '{"faceLibType":"blackFD","FDID":"1","FPID":"${employeeNo}"}`);
_data.append('img', fs.createReadStream('/C:/Users/ALIENWARE/Downloads/unnamed.jpg'));

let _config = {
    method: 'put',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'http://192.168.1.3/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FDSetUp?format=json',
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': 'language=en; WebSession_F82FED6D22=' + cookie,
        'Origin': 'http://192.168.1.3',
        'Referer': 'http://192.168.1.3/index.asp',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        ..._data.getHeaders()
    },
    data: _data
};

await axios.request(_config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined