# How convert Express.Multer.File to Blob data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs, multer

I have a **NestJs** project in my controller I accept an **Express.Multer.File** but I need to send it to another server. How can I convert it to **Blob** for passing to **FormData**?

```js
#action in my controller

    @Post('/upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('avatar'))
    async uploadUserProfileAvatar(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File){
        
        console.log(file)
        let blob = new Blob(file.mimetype)
        let formData = new FormData()
        //can't set because file is not Blob
        formData.append('file',file)


        let request$ = this.httpService.post('http://test_server/file',formData,{headers:{
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
        }}).pipe(
            map(response => response.data)
        )

        request$.subscribe( response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response
        })
    }
```

I will be grateful for every answer!

**EDIT:**

Thanks again for your help! As a result, I managed to successfully send the code in this way:

```
    @Post('/upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('avatar'))
    async uploadUserProfileAvatar(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File){

        const FormData = require('form-data');
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', Buffer.from(file.buffer) , file.originalname);


        let request$ = this.httpService.post('http://nginx_files/file',formData,{headers:formData.getHeaders()}).pipe(
                map(response => response.data)
            )

        request$.subscribe( response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response
        })
    }
```

Comment: `blob = new Blob(file.mimetype)` looks incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `formdata` package like this:

```js
  const FormData = require('form-data');

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileContent, 'file_name.ext');

  let request$ = this.httpService.post('http://test_server/file',
    formData,
    { headers: formData.getHeaders() }
  ).pipe(
            map(response => response.data)
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! But my question is, what is the advantage of this package over the standard FormData?

Comment: FormData is not a part of NodeJs, see also the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577074/1376618

Comment: unfortunately this code raises an error `TypeError: source.on is not a function` 
what could be the problem?

Comment: What code exactly? Can you update your post?

Answer (score 1):

@MiyRon

You get the Error "TypeError: source.on is not a function", because formData accepts only three types of elements. String, Buffer and Stream.

So you can fix it with:

```
formData.append('file', JSON.stringify(fileContent), 'file_name.ext');
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered same issue, but initial answer didn't work for me, had to add `Content-Length` header and `contentType`, so code looks something like this:

```js
import * as FormData from 'form-data';

// ...

    processFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', Buffer.from(file.buffer), {
            filename: file.originalname,
            contentType: file.mimetype,
        });

        return this.httpService
            .post('http://test_server/file', formData, {
                headers: {
                    ...formData.getHeaders(),
                    'Content-Length': `${formData.getLengthSync()}`,
                },
            })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.data));
    }
```

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/503#issuecomment-1007253651)